# Defining functions as derivatives

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I'm working on a model that requires a sum over a function that uses various coefficients. In order to make the sum easier to perform, I am trying to keep things general through the use of a coefficient array. Consider the set-up:

```
c={1,2,3,4},
f1[x_,n_]:=x^2*c[[n]]
f2[x_,n_]=D[f1[x,n],x]
```

I need to be able to define the derivative of `f1` as a new function `f2`. I have two issues. First, I cannot figure out how to specify that `c[[n]]` is a constant. The second is, I think that Mathematica is evaluating the differential each time `f2` is called. It would be better if Mathematica would evaluate the differential and then declare `f2` as the resulting derivative.

Note that `f2` is not a function declaration using "`:=`". The result is very different if that notation is used.

How do I specify elements obtained from a given array are constants? Can I evaluate a differential and then declare a function as the differential's result?

Comment: Instead of an array, define `c` as a function over $1,\dots,4$. `c[1] = 1; c[2] = 2; ...`

Comment: Define `c` as function `c[n_?NumericQ] := {1, 2, 3, 4}[[n]]`

Comment: For J.M.'s solution, do `ClearAll@c; Evaluate[Array[c, 4]] = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and use `c[n]` instead of `c[[n]]`. I prefer that one. If you're going to use @swish's answer, I would recommend `c[n_Integer]` in place of `c[n_?NumericQ]`.

Comment: The c[n_Integer] version seems to be working at the moment, more tests to come. How do I make it evaluate the differential once and then simply substitute values in when the function is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that with the way you defined `f2`, the error generated at the time of definition notwithstanding, `f2` still works properly.

The scope & context of your problem is not yet clear to me, but if it was me, I would make the code more general by making it more mathematical.  *Mathematica* can usually handle efficiently most problems that can be expressed in terms of multivariable calculus.

Consider the following:

```
ClearAll[c, f1, f2];
c = {1, 2, 3, 4};
f1[x_] := x^2*c;
f2[x_] = f1'[x] (* or D[f1[x],x] *)
(*
  {2 x, 4 x, 6 x, 8 x}
*)
```

Now `f1` and `f2` are vector-valued functions.  You can perform all the usually algebra & calculus operations on them, including extracting a component `f[2][[3]]`.